# Talend Open Studio For MDM + Postgresql + synchronization of two databases

Tags: database, postgresql, synchronization, talend

I have two database A and B(replica of A) now one live web application is
entering data into A now i want that the entries done in A should be
reflected in B.(i.e the changes in A should automatically reflect in B).

My sole purpose is synchronizing two databases and for that i have searched on **Talend**. I searched and came up with Talend MDM.I have installed MDM .I have searched on it but i am not getting whether it does database synchronization or not.Since there are other talend products like ESB,Data Integration etc. which one of them exactly is for syncing purpose.
Please suggest me.

Comment: Do you want 'all data' to be replicated or you want a subset (some tables/some columns/some records)? Please have a look at [link] http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Replication,_Clustering,_and_Connection_Pooling

Comment: I want all data to be replicated.

Comment: Try PostgreSQL's inbuilt replication. It should do what you want to do. But the slave will be in read-only mode. This wa not available in earlier versions (probably before 9.0). http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/warm-standby.html#STREAMING-REPLICATION

Comment: Thanx @Jayadevan i did replication with inbuilt feature of postgresql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IHMO, if you are looking for data replication between two databases having the same structure, then Talend is not what you are looking for.

Talend is an ETL tool (Extract Transform and Load). It would be applicable if in your case, your B database had a different structure than A. For that particular use case, you would use Talend in order to define some processing rules :

1. How do I extract data from A (Extract)
2. How do I transform A's data into B's data (Transform)
3. How do I store B's data (Load)

As mentioned by @jayadevan above, I would definitely look for inbuilt replication offered by your database.

Comment: AFAIK , I can use Talend to monitor oracle CDC(Change data capture) and tranform data into mysql right?